# How to connect Azure Account with multiple subscriptions via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage-account, azure-subscription

I am trying to get list of all storage account present in my subscription along with their GeoReplication properties.

I am using `Get-AzStorageAccount` command but I'm getting empty response even storage accounts are there.

I came to know that I connected to a subscription where there are no storage accounts. I don't know how to shift into another subscription of same Azure account via PowerShell.

I found that I can use `Set-Context` command but no idea how to use that.

Can anyone give me some idea about how to connect to different subscription and get that list of storage accounts???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wrestle with this a lot too. You need to set your context like so:

```
$subscriptionId = '1a1e0e55-74fb-4231-a84a-30b7900e656a';  # replacing this GUID with your subscription GUID

Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId | Set-AzContext;
```